# Using relative path in python

Tags: python, path

i have a `source path: C:\users\admin\Downloads\Application1` and I need to copy this to the `dest path: C:\users\admin\Documents\Packages`. Right now i am using absolute path to do this, but can i use relative path to copy from `"..\..\Application"` to `"..\..\Packages"` in python? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: you can do `C:\users\admin\Downloads\Application\..\..\Packages` using `os.path.join`. Your issue is unclear. Do you have some code you need improving?

Comment: That depends on the current working directory at the start of the interpreter. Relative paths are relative to `os.getcwd()`

Comment: yes, currently i use copytree functions to copy the contents from source path to dest path. i need to manually give the paths for source and dest. Instead, i want to impove it by giving relative paths where it my script can copy all the contents from any "C:\..\...\..\Application1" to "C:\..\Packages"

Comment: What difficulty are you having using the relative paths?

Comment: I am not sure how to use relative paths in this case. Can you please tell me how i can use it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below two steps;

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
copy_tree("..\\..\Application" , "..\\..\Packages")
```

Comment: It throws me an error saying "system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Can you check now again the above answer. i did small modification